# Using "if" inside an "onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Please before posting or commenting ... read and understand that this is inside an application that generates the web page and I cannot create a function I can only edit with will happen inside the onclick**

Is it possible to use a "if" function inside an "onclick".

The reason why I have to do this is because this "onclick" is used inside an application that I do not control the code, the only thing I can control is what happens inside the "onclick"

For example:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_NUMBER').value = '';"
```

I can write the:

```
document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_NUMBER').value = '';
```

I cannot declare any function in the webpage... cause it's an application that compiles the pages... I can only write what is written in the tag onclick...

But not a function. The page is generated by the application itself so I do not control the header.

What I need, a IF that checks an other ID and to change the value ONLY if the value of the other ID (REF_DOC_1_CHOICE) is NA (not applicable)

Any thoughts?

Comment: why dont you use function for that

Comment: Learn to read I CAN'T ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

though it is not a good practice to use inline javascript but you can use an if in onclick

```
onclick="document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_NUMBER').value = '';if(condition){dosomething}else{dosomething else}"
```

Comment: Thanks and trust me I know it's no a good practice but I have no choice in that situation... Thanks for taking the time to read and understand my problem!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use any inline statement you want. The `onclick` event is a function by itself. As you can define one in JS in the header:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').onclick = function() {
    var a = 2;
    if (a > 1) {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

You can also do so inline:

```
onclick="var a=2;if(a>1){a=3}else{a=-1}"
onclick="a == 12 && b = true || b = false"
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkBJV/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use ternary operator. Somehow like this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_CHOICE') == 'some_value'? (document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_NUMBER').value = '') : 0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function like this :

```
onclick="function(text){
             // My stuffs
             if(text==='test')
                 document.getElementById('REF_DOC_1_NUMBER').value = '';
        }";
```

Comment: @sdespont using `javascript:` in onclick is wrong. Also, you don't need to define an anonymous function to do this, you can just use that stuff inline completely.